# SSL certificate to cover subdomain sub.domain.com

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, lets-encrypt

I'm new to AWS server and I was recently handed a server to maintain. It freaks me out a little bit.

Let's say our domain is: abc.com and www.abc.com
I have already installed letsencrypt SSL certificate for these 2 domains. and they worked fine.

The problem now is that we need an unbounce page to divert traffic to a landing page (away from the buggy one we have on aws right now).

I, then, went on my DNSimple an reroute as follows:

> abc.com URL www.abc.com
>
> www.abc.com CNAME unbouncepages

--> abc.com and www.abc.com resolve to our landing page on unbounce

BUT, we still need the page we have set up on aws server. 
At the moment, I have this configured on DNSimple:

> sub.abc.com ALIAS xx.xx.xx.xx.xx (our AWS server public IP)

https://sub.abc.com will complain: `This page is insecure (broken HTTPS).`

My question is: How do I add SSL certificate to a subdomain on an apache AWS server?

Any suggestion is much appreciated

Comment: You have already added the cert for `www.abc.com` to AWS Apache?

Comment: yes I have. so abc.com and www.abc.com work just as expected.

Comment: But for `sub.abc.com` you can follow the same procedure as for `www.abc.com`, there is no difference.

Comment: As Dusan said "no difference" with Let's Encrypt. Traditionally there is another option - wildcard certificates. Those made sense when it was say $40 for one subdomain vs. $200 for unlimited subdomains via wildcard. With Let's Encrypt you can't do wildcards but you can add (practically speaking) as many subdomains as you want, each with their own cert.